# Lazer wifi connection

Tags: cables, wifi, laser

Would it be possible to create a Wifi cable that uses lasers to send information at light speed?

Comment: Yes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_optical_communication

Comment: electric signal also moves at light speed ...  `WiFi` and `cable` are mutually exclusive

Comment: Yes. Not only it is possible, it's already done. For more than 40 years already. Fiber optic cables use light to send information. Copper cables use electricity to transmit information. Unfortunately neither can work at speed of light (in vacuum), because the electromagnetic waves are not transmitted in air or vacuum. Also, there idea of using your home lighting or separate optical transceiver for example all over your house or office is already been invented. Not used much though.

Comment: Light always travels at light speed for the medium it uses,  but that isn’t  always secure if they tap into your data  at any router, unless adequate encryption is used. Your idea is not novel. Ideas are worthless unless it is implemented and results in profit.

Comment: @Justme told you about [fiber optic cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_communication). But Note! Fiber optics are not use because the signal travels down the cable any faster than an electrical signal would travel down a copper cable. Fiber optics are used because the [_bandwidth_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)) of a fiber connection potentially is greater than the bandwidth available with a copper cable of the same length.

Comment: [Already done in free space as well](https://x.company/projects/taara/).

Comment: There's a IEEE802.11 standard for WLAN over infrared light in free space propagation. That's more than 20 years old. It's hard to steal an idea that's been done, and tested, commercially manufacturered and long has been superseeded. As others say, *all* electromagnetic waves travel at the speed of light. That's how that is defined....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You are confusing several things.

> Lazer wifi connection.

LASER stands for  "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation" so it's spelt with an 'S', not a 'Z'. You may be confusing it with a brand name for a laser tag game, for example.

> Would it be possible to create a Wifi cable ...

[image]

*Figure 1. Laser pointers showing highly columnated beams. Image credit: [Netweb01](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Laser_pointers.jpg) on Creative Commons.*

No. WiFi uses radio waves to transmit over a wide area. Laser uses light and one of its main features is that it produces a collimated narrow beam. Fibre optic cables are used for telecoms and internet backbone to transmit data from point to point but not to broadcast like WiFi. Laser can also be used to transmit point to point through the air or space. The collimated beam helps in these configurations and the laser beam can be modulated to carry information.

[image]

*Figure 2. Optical fibres in a network switch. These are point-to-point connections. Image source: [Electrical Engineering Portal](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/optical-communication-cables).*

> ... that uses lasers to send information at light speed?

The light will travel at whatever the speed of light is for that medium.

> Light travels at approximately 300,000 kilometers per second in a vacuum, which has a refractive index of 1.0, but it slows down to 225,000 kilometers per second in water (refractive index of 1.3) and 200,000 kilometers per second in glass (refractive index of 1.5). Source: [Olympus LifeScience](https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/microscope-resource/primer/lightandcolor/speedoflight/).

The data speed will depend on the modulation technique and will be rated in bits per second.

> DO NOT STEAL MY IDEA.

I think you're safe enough.

Comment: It is astonishing that a "microprocessor" still does not have, to my knowledge, multiple "optical fibers" interfaces which would allow them to be superimposed, like bricks to be assembled, in three dimensions and being connected automatically "by simple contact "to build a supercomputer? All this while seeing this "beautiful photo" of spaghetti network connection cables ...

Comment: @Antonio51, A "microprocessor" typically is a single IC chip, and except for certain, highly specialized applications, it typically is a CMOS chip. I don't know that there is any cost-effective way to fabricate LED emitters on a CMOS chip. Also note: Even if there was a way to do it, the _size_ of a useful LED emitter and the amount of power that it consumes might be substantially greater than the size of the couple of transistors that drive a typical CMOS output.

Comment: I did not think especially about integration of diodes or lasers on the CMOS chip die, but superposition of a dedicated circuitry connected just above or below and driven by the processor ? Not possible ? Ok, this will heat a little ...

Comment: @Antonio51 multiple highly complex fiber interfaces on one chip are standard on the ASICs that backbone equipment manufacturers design. You don't *want* to put a relatively high-power laser diode directly on top of a high-speed chip, because both need cooling.

Comment: @Antonio51 the science of bringing photons directly onto the chip, by the way, is called photonics, and it's a large field with hundreds of research institutes, companies, products and value propositions.

Comment: Ok ... It was just a thought ... I haven't kept myself up to date for quite some time in this area ... nor in quantum "mecanics" ...   :-)